# SQL RegEx Syntax With an NVARCHAR Datatype

Tags: sql-server, regex, nvarchar

I have two pieces of SQL code, one of which uses a VARCHAR data type and one of which uses an NVARCHAR data type.  I am receiving different results depending on which data type that I am using.

```
DECLARE @a NVARCHAR(1024) = ' ~`!@#$%^&*()_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+-'
SELECT CASE WHEN @a NOT LIKE REPLICATE('[ -~A-Z0-9]', LEN(@a)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(1024) = ' ~`!@#$%^&*()_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+-'
SELECT CASE WHEN @a NOT LIKE REPLICATE('[ -~A-Z0-9]', LEN(@a)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

How can I get the first piece of code to work like the second piece of code?

Comment: Please can you share example result of both queries

Comment: The queries are posted above in the original question.  One returns a 1 and one returns a 0.

Comment: With SQL Server 2017 CU17 I get `1` for both queries. Which version are you using?

Comment: If you remove **space** from queries: `[ -~A-Z0-9]` then you will get `1` for both queries

Comment: SQL Server 2014.  I'm basically looking to get 0s when the any of the first 128 printable ASCII Characters are in the string.

Comment: For an NVARCHAR data type.

Comment: If you remove the space the queries should fail because there is a space in varaible a.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem with your examples [dB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a44c4da90ab59c1572c4de36c62f66e)

Comment: Try moving the `-` at the very end just before the closing `]`.

Comment: @SalmanA - The - is a reserved character.  The RegEx [ -~A-Z0-9] means all characters from the space to the ~, all letters A-Z and all numbers 0-9.  This works when I declare the string as a VARCHAR, but not as an NVARCHAR.  Wondering why.